# What is the standard way to incorporate a mask in a custom pytorch geometric dataset?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am using pytorch geometric, and I need to create several masks for different experiments. I am creating a mask in the `process` function of my dataset class. Here is a simplified snippet:

```
 data = from_networkx(graph)

 mask = torch.zeros(data.num_nodes, dtype=torch.bool)

 for i in range(data.num_nodes):
   if data.attr[i]==attr:
     mask[i]=True
   else:
     mask[i]=False

 data.mask= mask

 torch.save(data, os.path.join(self.processed_dir, f'{filename}.pt'))
```

However, I want to access the induced subgraph by the masked nodes i.e., I want to keep all nodes in the mask, and I want to keep all edge between nodes in the mask. It seems like there would be a convenient function for doing this already, but it seems I need to also create a mask for the edge indices as well?

I can create the code to achieve this, but I imagine there is a standard procedure for creating such a mask maybe using mostly built in functions. If so, I prefer not to create my own method. Please, any suggestion on the standard way to achieve this?